# Crash With New Facebook SDK 3.20 and iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ios5.1

I am trying to integrate the latest facebook ios sdk 3.20 for my existing ios app, but It start crashing on iOS 5.1.1 devices every time i try to login using facebook. Please see the screen sort attached

[image]

Let me If you need some more information for the same

Thanks

Comment: show ur crash report ...

Comment: If you see the bottom window after the first line..
The Log shows the error, but i am not able to get the issue

Comment: use social framework because it is apple native to avoid crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see on their [SDK page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) that the Facebook SDK supports iOS 6.0 and greater. They appear to be using new features of Objective C that are not present in older versions of iOS SDK.

> The Facebook SDK for iOS versions 3.17+ supports iOS 6.x and higher.
>   Support for iOS 5.x was dropped in version 3.17 of the SDK.

Comment: Not to nit pick your revision, but language features are actually more a part of the SDK as I had it before. Once compiled and put onto the device, the language features you used to make your own executable are moot since you are just left with machine code in the binary.